# PyDIP diplib Installing

Tags: python, module, diplib

I am learning python and want to setup PyDIP. I followed https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib/blob/master/INSTALL_Windows.md steps and I can't import PyDIP.

[CMake page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4JVY.png)

[Visual Studio1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmnAW.png)

[Visual Studio2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AamW3.png)

[Error Pythn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRHKO.png)

[paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAtlP.png)

[Brows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kGhl.png)

What is my issue? I haven't use Cmake or Visual Studio. I don't have any experience with Python binary's or wheels.

Comment: When I viewed the page, The instructions were clearly given. Please tell what exactly is the problem. If I am not wrong, its ```No module name PyDIP```

Comment: Yes , ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyDIP'

Comment: When you run the `pip_install` target, make sure that the Python environment you run it in is the same as the Python environment that you want to use the package in.

Comment: Also, the documentation you link instructs to use `import diplib as dip` not `import PyDIP as dip`. Did you find an old bit of code that imports `PyDIP`? I’d like to fix those, please point me to it.

Comment: @CrisLuengo thanks for your intereset . Yes I typed  `import diplib as dip` and it yielded same error.  When i tried both PyDIP and diplib in Visual Studio 2019 `No module named 'diplib.PyDIP_bin` error occured.   I' am crious if i typed just pip install diplib what kind of library i get. When i tried i couldn't use 
 `SetPixelSize(dip.PixelSize(dip.PhysicalQuantity` commands and so on.  Thank you.

Comment: Do you need the latest version? Or would the official 3.0.0 release be OK? If so, just `pip install diplib` should do the trick. Just make sure that you install it within whatever virtual environment you want to use it in. I have the feeling that the `pip_install` target was not run in the right Python virtual environment.

Comment: @CrisLuengo thank you so much.